# How does class know associated type?

Tags: swift, swiftui

`UIViewRepresentable` has...

```
associatedtype Coordinator = Void
```

In an instance, I have...

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
   Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
   ...
}
```

If I add...

```
typealias Coordinator = Self.Coordinator
```

the compiler says...

> Invalid redeclaration of 'Coordinator'

...referring to the nested class.

So, what does `Coordinator = Void` mean and why does defining a nested class specify the associate type? Does it infer it from the return type of `makeCoordinator`? Why won't it let me additionally explicitly specify it using `typealias Coordinator = Self.Coordinator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what does Coordinator = Void mean and why does defining a nested class specify the associate type?

`Coordinator = Void` means that coordinator is optional and you can have representable without coordinator, ie. `Void` is default type.

> Does it infer it from the return type of makeCoordinator?

Yes, it does.

> Why won't it let me additionally explicitly specify it using typealias Coordinator = Self.Coordinator?

Because `typealias` introduces new type, but here you want `Coordinator = Coordinator`, so compiler reports duplication. If you want you can introduce it as

`typealias OneMoreCoordinator = Self.Coordinator`